# Monkeypatching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

Is monkeypatching a good development practice? When should I monkeypatch rather than, say, fork a gem and make the patch on the forked project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, monkey patching is never a good practice. However, I often use it for very special cases distinct to the application. In all other cases I'd prefer forking the gem or plugin and install the forked gem right into the gems folder of my application.

I'm also having a few tools modules which monkey patch some classes to inject special purpose behaviour into some standard classes for reuse in different application - but these are still special enough to not be useful to the public, or it is just infeasible to create forks.

So in the end it's a decision of specialization and compatibility. Always keep in mind that monkey patching is more likely going to break expected behaviour of other plugins or gems you may use in your project. This may become even more imminent after updating components in your working application ecosystem (or the outer supporting ecosystem, like Rails and its dependencies).

Comment: But if you monkeypatch in a new method that isn't in the public interface anyway, it won't affect gems/plugins.

Comment: @math this is what I meant by upgrading the ecosystem... One time your new method name may incidently be part of the new gem/plugin version... But otherwise you're right of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you practice responsible duck punching, it can be as easy to support as a project specific local copy of a gem.  It depends entirely on your diligence documenting upgrade problems with either solution.  It's easy to say that either you or a support developer wouldn't recklessly replace that gem in vendor/gems a year from now, but it happens.  Forking the project, patching it locally, and then submitting a pull request and having it make it back into the main gem is the ideal situation.

You need to stick to a couple of rules on duck punching though if you elect this route:

- The patch has to sit in a blatantly obvious location.  lib/[gem_name]_extensions.rb would be where I would first look as a support developer checking out a defect.
- The patch should have a large amount of documentation surrounding it.  It should outline potential upgrade nightmares.
- The patch should be done on a different module that is then included into original module/class ActiveSupport style.  This allows a support dev to call problem_method.ancestors and see a monkeypatch in progress.

This would be a way to do it in a way that keeps the old method around (for fun and games) and allows you to trace it more easily with a problem_method.ancestors().

```
#lib/mongomapper_extensions.rb
module MongomapperExensions
  module ProblemClassExensions
    alias :old_problem_method :problem method
    def problem_method
      #guerilla code goes here!
    end
  end
end
class ProblemClass
  include MongoMapperExtensions::ProblemClassExtensions
end
```